# Convert from currency to Integer in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I'm using PHPExcel(@v1.8.0) to read data in order to save it in my database

I can successfully load and read the file but I've encountered a problem when reading a column styled as "currency" (for the record, data is stored as a number Eg:12154,018037749)

[image: This is how the data looks]

As I read it without any modifications data load as:
'Price' => string '$ 12,154.02'

How can I read it as a number? Preferably as an integer (I do not care about cents, so I'm cool with truncating those)

I have tried to set the format to number

```
$activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$activeSheet->getStyle('H:H')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);
```

And then convert it to array:

```
$sheetData = $activeSheet->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

But data is still the same, is there something missing? I have thought about treating it as an string and then convert it but doesn't sounds performant...

Comment: Thanks David, adding the line $reader->load('path_to_excel_file.xlsx'); allowed me to read it as long and then converting it to integer, fixing the issue